# Codeigniter query array doesn't display first record but displays else

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Codeigniter query  array ignores first row but  displays  rest of the rows,what could  be  the reason for this???...

```
function index() {
$date = date('Y-m-d');
/* $result = $this->smsgateway->SendAbsentSMS(date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($date))); */
$student = $this->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);
print_r($student);
}

public function student_daily_attendance($date) {
     $this->db->select('students.id,students.firstname,students.lastname,students.guardian_phone,students.roll_no,classes.id,classes.class,sections.id,sections.section,student_attendences.*,student_session.id,student_session.class_id,student_session.section_id,student_session.session_id');
    $this->db->from('students');
    $this->db->join('student_session', 'student_session.student_id = students.id');
    $this->db->join('classes', 'classes.id = student_session.class_id');
    $this->db->join('sections', 'sections.id = student_session.section_id');
    $this->db->join('student_attendences', 'student_attendences.student_session_id = students.id');
    $this->db->where('date', $date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: paste "student_daily_attendance" function's code.

Comment: What does `student_daily_attendance()` function do in your `stuattendence_model`?

Comment: pasted the function

Answer (score 0):

```
function index() {
$date = date('Y-m-d');
/* $result = $this->smsgateway->SendAbsentSMS(date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($date))); */
$student = $this->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);
print_r($student);
}

public function student_daily_attendance($date) {
     $this->db->select('students.id,students.firstname,students.lastname,students.guardian_phone,students.roll_no,classes.id,classes.class,sections.id,sections.section,student_attendences.*,student_session.id,student_session.class_id,student_session.section_id,student_session.session_id');
    $this->db->from('students');
    $this->db->join('student_session', 'student_session.student_id = students.id');
    $this->db->join('classes', 'classes.id = student_session.class_id');
    $this->db->join('sections', 'sections.id = student_session.section_id');
    $this->db->join('student_attendences', 'student_attendences.student_session_id = students.id');
    $this->db->where('DATE(date)', $date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Just Change where query like this $this->db->where('DATE(date)', $date);

Comment: what is the data type of date field

Comment: Apologies Rajat, the database table had a record of student whom i deleted thus it was showing one less record.

Comment: Ok..You can also use above code . it will give you more accurate result

Comment: Sure Rajat Gupta, Thanks a lot sir for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, the database table had a record of student whom i deleted thus it was showing one less record.